# Powershell .Replace RegEx

Tags: powershell, replace

RegEx for Replace is kicking my butt.  I am trying find:

> value="COM8"/>

in a text file and replace "COM8" with another com port (ie "COM9", "COM13", etc).

```
(Get-Content 'C:\Path\File.config').Replace('/".*?"', '"COM99"') | Set-Content 'C:\Path\File.config'
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Get-Content` produces a list of strings. `Replace()` is called on each string via [member enumeration](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2012/06/13/new-v3-language-features/). Meaning, you're calling the [`String.Replace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, not the [`Regex.Replace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. The former does only normal string replacements.

Use the [`-replace`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx) operator instead:

```
(Get-Content 'C:\Path\File.config') -replace '=".*?"', '="COM99"' |
    Set-Content 'C:\Path\File.config'
```